# Nested Binding With WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I am newbie to WPF and curious to know how to nested bind the properties in WPF.  I have made a sample app for better understanding. Please find below the following scenario's.

### **Working Code:**

> UserControl1 >> MainWindow

Created a UserControl and included it in the mainWindow.

*UserControl1.xaml*

```
<StackPanel>
     <TextBox x:Name="text1" Text="{Binding MyTextUC1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
     <TextBox />
</StackPanel>
```

*UserControl1.xaml.cs*

```
 public UserControl1()
 {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.DataContext = this;
 }

 public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextUC1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyTextUC1", typeof(string),    typeof(UserControl1));

public string MyTextUC1
{
   get { return (string)GetValue(MyTextUC1Property); }
   set { SetValue(MyTextUC1Property, value); }
}
```

*MainWindwo.xaml*

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:UserControl1 x:Name="text1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=text1, Path=MyTextUC1}" />
</StackPanel>
```

On running this,   **text changes in the `TextBox` of UserControl1 got reflected in `TextBlock` of MainWindow.**

### **Not Working:**

> UserControl1 >> UserControl2 >> MainWindow

Created a UserControl(usercontrol1) and included it in another UserControl(usercontrol2) and then included the UserControl2 in mainWindow.

*UserControl1.xaml & UserControl1.xaml.cs*

```
//Same as Working Code
```

*UserControl2.xaml*

```
<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1 x:Name="text2" MyTextUC1="{Binding MyTextUC2,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

*UserControl2.xaml.cs*

```
 public UserControl2()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     this.DataContext = this;
 }

 public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextUC2Property =
     DependencyProperty.Register("MyTextUC2", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl2));       

 public string MyTextUC2
 {
     get { return (string)GetValue(MyTextUC2Property); }
     set { SetValue(MyTextUC2Property, value); }
 }
```

*MainWindwo.xaml*

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:UserControl2 x:Name="text1"/>   //UserControl2 contains UserControl1
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=text1, Path=MyTextUC2}" />
</StackPanel>
```

On Running this, **text changes in the `TextBox` of UserControl2 NOT REFLECTED in `TextBlock` of MainWindow.**

I'm pretty sure that this is a basic thing in WPF and I may be implementing this in wrong way.  Can someone suggest me where I am wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the Debug Output you will see the following error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MyTextUC2' property not found on 'object' ''UserControl1' (Name='text2')'. BindingExpression:Path=MyTextUC2; DataItem='UserControl1' (Name='text2'); target element is 'UserControl1' (Name='text2'); target property is 'MyTextUC1' (type 'String')

The problem is with this binding:

```
<local:UserControl1 x:Name="text2" MyTextUC1="{Binding MyTextUC2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

It is looking for the `MyTextUC2` property in `UserControl1`. It is because you set the `DataContext` in `UserControl1`'s constructor to `this` (`UserControl1`). So every binding on `UserControl1` will be evaluated against `UserControl1`'s `DataContext` (which is itself).

If you change it to this:

```
<local:UserControl1 x:Name="text2" 
                    MyTextUC1="{Binding MyTextUC2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl2}}}" />
```

it should start working.